# Survey data cleanup

Tags: python, dataframe, parsing, survey

I have an excel file with :

Name : Column 1: John
Survey response for Ques 1: Column 2 : Agree: 25; Disagree:45; somewhat agree:67 ; don't care:34

What is the easiest way to parse the responses from each ques (ques 1 thru 10) in a dataframe?

I tried. `.str.split(" ; ", n=3, expand = True)` and it doesnt work.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VI7MI.png)

Comment: can you share some of your code?

Answer (score 0):

How about using regex?

```
import re
text = '''Agree: 25; Disagree:45; somewhat agree:67; don't care:34'''

result = re.findall(r'''[; ]*([^:]+)[^\d]+(\d+)''', text)
```

with proper regex, you should be able to extract keys and values

```
print(result)

[('Agree', '25'), ('Disagree', '45'), ('somewhat agree', '67'), ("don't care", '34')]
```